# Proof of density of smooth functions in $H(\operatorname{curl})$ with $L^2$ tangential trace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement that is presented in the book “[Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198508885.001.0001)” by Peter Monk. The original source of the proof is a 1997 paper [Un résultat de densité pour les équations de Maxwell](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0764-4442(97)86998-4) by Ben Belgacem, Bernardi, Costabel, Dauge. Unfortunately, in this paper, written in French, it is even less explained why the steps in question are valid.

First we define the following sets ($\nu$ denotes the normal vector on the boundary):
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\curl}{\operatorname{curl}}
H_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega) &= \{u \in H(\curl,\Omega) \;|\; u \times \nu \in L^2_t(\partial \Omega)\}, \\
\hat{H}_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega) &= \{u \in H_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega) \;|\; \curl u \cdot \nu = 0\},
\end{align*}
where $L^2_t(\partial\Omega)$ denotes all tangential $L^2$ functions on the boundary (i.e. $u\cdot \nu = 0$).

> **Lemma 3.53.** The space $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense in
> $\hat{H}_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega)$ (w.r.t. $\lVert u\rVert_{H_{\text{imp}}}^2 = \lVert u\rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert\curl u\rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert u \times \nu\rVert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2 $).

The statement itself is already a little bit imprecise, because I think it is not meant that $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega}) \cap \hat{H}_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega)$ is dense in $\hat{H}_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega)$, but rather that for every $f \in\hat{H}_{\text{imp}}(\curl,\Omega)$ there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ that converges to $f$ w.r.t. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{H_{\text{imp}}}$. ($f_n$ does not need to satisfy $\curl f_n \cdot \nu = 0$.)

If it helps I can also copy the proof of the statement, but I think I can isolate my questions.

There are two steps that are (at least for my understanding) not sufficiently explained:

**First step**

> If $(\nu \times \nabla p) \times \nu \in L^2(\partial\Omega)$ (the
> tangential trace of $\nabla p$ as an element of $H(\curl,\Omega)$),
> then $\nabla_{\partial\Omega} p$ exists
> ($p\bigr\rvert_{\partial\Omega} \in H^1(\partial \Omega)$) and
> $\nabla_{\partial\Omega} p = (\nu\times \nabla p) \times \nu$.

I can see that the reverse is true: If $\nabla_{\partial\Omega}p$ exists, then $\nabla_{\partial\Omega} p = (\nu\times \nabla p) \times \nu$. However, I don't see how one can show the claimed direction. Maybe, if you can provide me some good references of $H^1$ spaces on Lipschitz boundaries I can come further.

**Second step**

For notational simplicity I denote that tangential trace by $\pi_{\tau}$ ($\pi_{\tau} f = (\nu \times f) \times \nu$). The second step that I don't understand is:

> If $$ \langle A \times \nu, \pi_{\tau} \phi\rangle = \langle u \times\nu, \pi_{\tau} \phi \rangle \quad\text{for all}\quad \phi \in X_{T} = H(\curl,\Omega) \cap H_0(\operatorname{div},\Omega), $$ then $A \times\nu = u \times \nu$.

I am aware that the normal component, that is zero for all $\phi \in X_T$, is not relevant. However, this would still mean that $\pi_{\tau} X_T$ is dense in $\pi_\tau H(\curl,\Omega)$, which is not immediately clear to me. Maybe $X_T$ is even dense in $H(\curl,\Omega)$, but I don't see that.